# A case of Taylor Lagrange inequality up to order 2

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, inequality

*I am trying to understand the following inequality.*

For every $t,x>0$, $c>0$ is a constant, and $\nu$ a finite positive measure on $\mathbb R^+$
$$
\mid\int^x_0 (e^{-ct}-e^{-yt}) \nu(dy)\mid\leq\frac{t^2}{2}\int^x_0 (c-y)^2\nu(dy)
$$
This inequality uses a *Taylor-Lagrange* up to the second order.

I do not understand how to compute it ? what is the remainder in this case ?

---

Maybe isolate the term $e^{-ct}-e^{-yt}$, and show it is less or equal to $\frac{t^2}{2}(c-y)^2$.
In this case $e^{-ct}-e^{-yt}$ is seen as a *remainder* for the Taylor inequality ?